# Reading Text File error C

Tags: c, text-files, fgets

When generating 4 character hashes and writing it to a text file I run into an error where if I try and print the hashes to the console it only prints the first line of the text file. Weirdly enough it prints the whole text file to the console if I get rid of the `generateHashTable();` line and edit the text file by adding a space or something. I don't understand why it does this.

Comment: It's not clear what your code is doing. Can you show the definition of `generateHashTable()`? Also not clear *which* `generateHashTable();` line you are getting rid of to make it work. There are two. Does `generateHashTable()` create the file `program.txt`, or does your program only *read* that file?

Comment: `close(ftpr);` there seems like a typo. and `perror` does not exit the program, so you continue even if `fptr==NULL`.  Fix those first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem is this:

```
fwrite("\n", sizeof("\n"), 1, fptr);
```

`fwrite()` will write two characters here, a `'\n'` and an `'\0'`, which, while not incorrect, is clearly not what you want. What this will cause is every single line in your file after the first to begin with a null character. When you try then to `printf()` those lines, it'll stop at that null character because that's where it thinks the end of the string is, the end result being nothing will be printed. This is why it's only printing out your first line. You should replace this line with:

```
fputc('\n', fptr);
```

A couple other obvious errors:

```
char *c=malloc(sizeof 5);
```

is almost certainly not what you want. This will allocate a number of bytes equal to `sizeof(int)`. What you need is:

```
char * c = malloc(5);
```

If you're on a system with 32 bit `int`s, the following line:

```
c[4] = '\0';
```

gives you undefined behavior immediately, since you're trying to write to the fifth byte of a four byte allocation of memory.

Then this:

```
if (fptr == NULL)
```

why are you checking if `fopen()` returned successfully *after* you've done all your reading and writing to the file? You should be checking it *before* you do that.

Since you don't show your definitions for things like `E()`, `fptr`, `chunkout`, and the like, it's quite possible there are other glaring errors that cannot be determined in the absence of those definitions.

Comment: Thanks fputc worked the textfile prints correctly now.